# CSS problem between Visual Studio IDE and IIS

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio

I'm not a web developer, so what seems weird to me is hopefully an easy one.

Have an existing ASP.NET web site which I need to modify, using VS 2008.  I worked on an aspx page and somehow the CSS settings changed and messed the page up badly.  I restored the old CSS files and now the page is fine again in the IDE but still a mess when I run the project.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Steven Segal

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: This is probably it. You can try hitting Ctrl-F5 in your browser too to force a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that website needs authentication (i.e. FormsAuthentication) ?

If so, the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server also blocks css files and images making your web app look like crap in Visual Studio... IIS however doesn't have this behaviour, so when you deploy your site, all looks nice and tidy...